# Why is the class name of the html element not changed?

Tags: javascript

Only one div in my html code has a class of active-tab. I want to remove the active-tab class from the div.

```
var activeTab = document.querySelector('.active-tab');
activeTab.className.replace("active-tab",'');
```

The above code does not seem to work. Please explain why.

**PS - Please don't give me any jQuery answers.**

Comment: You need to do `activeTab.className = activeTab.className.replace("active-tab",'');`

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the `className`,

```
var activeTab = document.querySelector('.active-tab');
activeTab.className = activeTab.className.replace("active-tab",'');
```

You are simply getting the result of `className` (a string), manipulating it and leaving that string alone. You have to set the modified string back to the className property of that element to accomplish your task.

Comment: Just to add, strings is JavaScript are immutable so `activeTab.className.replace('"active-tab", '');` wouldn't work since you can't alter the string itself. Instead it returns the a new string with your modifications which you overwrite as shown in above in the answer.